# How to use gemset version of gem instead of default version?

Tags: ruby, rbenv, rbenv-gemset

I have set up rbenv and rbenv-gemset. I installed the Ruby and created the gemset.

Using OSX, there is the default version 1.17.2:

```
> gem list bundler
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (default: 1.17.2, 1.7.3)
```

I installed 1.7.3 with

```
> gem install bundler -v 1.7.3
Successfully installed bundler-1.7.3
1 gem installed
```

```
> rbenv rehash
> bundle -v
Bundler version 1.17.2
```

How to use 1.7.3?

Comment: If you don't need 1.7.2, you could remove it.

Comment: @BillDoughty - Apparently bundler was installed with OSX (10.15.6). How would you know if the OS or other system software was using it?

Comment: If you're using `rbenv`, you're working in a separate ruby environment isolated from system Ruby, so it doesn't matter.  You can type `which ruby` in the terminal to make sure you're using an rbenv Ruby.  It should show something like `/Users/username/.rbenv/shims/ruby`.  If the path doesn't show .rbenv, you're not using an rbenv Ruby.